# How to select first of several items in JSON that exists?

Tags: javascript, json

JSON files are compromised of a series of key's and values. I know the potential key's in a given JSON, but not whether or not they have corresponding non-empty values.  I have loaded the JSON file into an object called JSON.  I want to find the first of several possible key's with a value and then assign that value to a variable.  When I say "first" I mean "first" according to a priority list that is not related to the structure of the JSON:

I could do the following and it works:

```
if(json.age)
    myValue = json.age;
else if(json.classYear)
    myValue = json.classYear;
else if(json.seniority)
    myValue = json.seniority
else
    myValue = false;
```

This works but sucks for several reasons:

1. It is slow to write
2. It is annoying to rewrite the key value name each twice in each row
3. It is a little hard to read
4. It is very difficult to reason with programatically. I don't have a use case that requires this, but I can imagine wanting to arbitrarily change the order of priority from within my code.
5. While not terribly slow to process, I can imagine that some other approach may compute faster.

These reasons lead me to believe that the method listed above is not ideal.  Is there some other pattern that would be better?

(Note: I recognize that this question borders on a "how best to" as opposed to "how to" phrasing.  I know SO is not wild about that sort of question and I don't mean my question to be interpreted as such.  Rather, my question should be interpreted as asking, "is there some design pattern that is particularly suited for the problem describe above?)

(Note: I will only accept a vanilla answer, but feel free to provide other answers if you believe they will be helpful).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). You'll still have to write out all of the property names, but I'm not sure there's a way to accomplish this task without doing that.

```
const myValue = json.age || json.classYear || json.senority || false;
```

Comment: And I'd fix the spelling of your property name. "seniority" != "senority". :)

Comment: This is exactly why I come to SO.  Thank you!

Comment: Note that this won't give the correct result if any of the properties could legitimately have a value of `0` or an empty string (or other falsey value).

Comment: Thank you for the note that is helpful to know nnnnn

Comment: Why does this need to be a const why can't you just do this with a variable?

Comment: @nnnnnn That's true. I assumed based on the context.

Comment: @COMisHARD You can use const, let, or var. I assumed you'd be returning this value as part of a function, so const is appropriate because you won't be mutating the value.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so if you have a one-dimensional hash table and an array for the priority of keys, then you can use an algorithm like this to select the first one available:

```
function grab(hash, keyPriority) {
  var value;
  keyPriority.some(function (key) {
    if (hash.hasOwnProperty(key)) { // check if the property exists
      value = hash[key];
      return true; // break out of loop
    }
  });
  return value;
}
```

usage:

```
grab({ c: 3, d: 4 }, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']) // 3
```

You can modify this to work by truthy values, or undefined/null by changing `hash.hasOwnProperty(key)` to `hash[key]` or `hash[key] != null` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with using a bit of `JQuery` then the following code snippet should do the job I guess.

```
$.each(JSONObj, function(key, value){
    if (!(value === "" || value === null)){
        myValue = value;
        return false; //to break the loop once a valid value is found
    }
});
```

This will assign the first valid value to your variable `myValue` and will also exit the loop once a valid value is found.

Comment: This won't work, because it doesn't test the properties in the specific order required (which is, as the OP said, not necessarily related to the original JSON structure's order (also object properties don't have an inherent order like array elements do)).